# IPython loading R - ImportError: cannot import name conversion

Tags: python, r, import, ipython

I'm trying to work in R from Ipython  but i get this error when load the rmagic >> rpy2.ipython (now) library: (I've only copied the final, not all code)

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py in <module>()
      5 rpy2.rinterface.initr()
      6 
----> 7 from . import conversion
      8 
      9 class RObjectMixin(object):

ImportError: cannot import name conversion
```

A month ago this works fine and i don't change anything since then.

I researched for this on web but all answers said to upgrade all program versions and none resolve my problem. Probably, i did something wrong.

I have installed R version 3.1.1, Python version 2.7.9 and Ipython 4.0.0. The latest versions in powerpc64 processor.

Comment: you must have changed something. updated a library. patched R. move home directories. _something_ had to have changed.

Comment: Thanks! Updated to the last version, Jupyter was installed and appears a bug in IPython 4.0 that it works changed the file rpy/ipython/rmagic.py:  https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/pull-requests/43/bug-simplegeneric-was-moved-out-of-ipython/diff